# How to upload a text file without saving and parse the content into a database with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, file, parsing, upload

I need to upload a text file without saving it in the database. My goal is to upload this file and automatically have to take your content and save it in my database.

my file: data.txt

```
name age occupation
julio 19 student
ramon 20 student
```

my database:

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
   def change
     create_table: students do |t|
       t.string "name"
       t.integer "age"
       t.string "occupation"

       t.timestamps
     end
   end
end
```

Does anyone have any idea how this can be done? I searched on the internet, but found no solution to my case. I need help.

Comment: Seems like a combo of any upload library and CSV processing would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

```
= form_tag url, {multipart: true} do
  = file_field_tag :file
  ....
```

in controller

```
if params[:file]
  lines = params[:file].tempfile.readlines.map(&:chomp) #readlines from file & removes newline symbol
  lines.shift #remove first line 
  lines.each do |l| 
    m = l.match(/(\S+)\s(\d+)\s(\S+)/) #parse line 
    Student.create {name: m[1],age: m[2], occupation: m[3]}
  end
end
```

Comment: but it is better to do that asynchroniusly (delayed_job,redis...)

Comment: how can i translate this form for erb format? i don't use haml.

Comment: just add <% %> <%= form_tag url, {:multipart => true} do %>

Comment: i try it, but it returns this message: "undefined local variable or method `url'"

Comment: ofc) please read  
guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#uploading-files and create your route, controller, action ...

Comment: so, i try this: <%= form_tag({:action => :upload}, :multipart => true) do %> and i create the def upload in my controller, but it returns other error: "No route matches {:action=>"upload", :controller=>"students"}"

Comment: in routes.rb add post "students#upload" and  read everything on this page guides.rubyonrails.org )) and don't forget to accept and upvote answers and comments if they help u